# Prepositional phrases ‘fronting’ a sentence

Tags: syntax-trees

Hi Everybody (please help),

I’m having trouble deciphering how to diagram a sentence with the adjunctive prepositional phrase at the front of the sentence. As from ‘The boy found the cat in the garden’ to ‘In the garden, the boy found the cat’ and other similar sentences.

Thus, how do I show this ‘movement’ using X-Bar?

Any and all comments will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That’s topicalisation so you just combine the topicalised NP with the IP to the right.

Comment: [S in the garden [S the boy found the cat ] ]  This type of adjunction was dubbed "Chomsky adjunction" by Haj Ross in his MIT dissertation.